# Automation for Jira: Copy a comment if it is not restricted to a specific group

Tags: automation, jira, jql, automation-for-jira

I have created an Automation task that copies comments from a backlog/sprint card to the associated service desk ticket. This works great. However, I would like to only copy comments if they are not restricted.

**Current Automation setup:**

> When: Issue commented
>
> For Linked Issues
>
> > Types: causes
>
> If: Issue matches JQL
>
> > Project = *service desk name*
>
> Then: Add comment to issue
>
> > *comment text*

I want to add a "*Compare two values*" check before the "*For Linked Issues*" step that checks if the comment has been restricted to developers. If the comment was made on a service desk ticket, I could use *{{comment.internal}}* to check if the comment was public or internal. I don't know what the same value is for comments made on backlog cards since the restriction options are different. I have tried *{{comment.developers}}* but Automation doesn't know what to do with that value.

[IMG: Comment restricted to developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88oZB.png)